# Beginner with QuickBlox

Tags: android, ios, quickblox

I am developing an app (`iOS` and `Android`) which supports real time messaging and grouped/ one to one audio-video calling.

Queries:

1. Does `QuickBlox` supports above listed features?
2. Can I implement and test the above listed features with Starter package(free one) during the development phase?
3. Can I upgrade my package when app is live on `AppStore`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes quickblox supports all your listed feature. Check this out http://quickblox.com/developers/VideoChat
2. i have already implemented "One-to-one, group and private messaging".. not sure about Video and Audio call for starter package.
3. hope you will.. Because upgrading a package wont change the SDK... ..**But Quickblox already updated their package more than 5 times from oct-2015 - feb -2016. ** check with the documentation

Answer (score 0):

From [Quickblox pricing page](https://quickblox.com/plans/), under Notes section:

> The Quickblox Free tier is a fully functioning instance of Quickblox. It can be used for live apps but as a Free tier it does not include dedicated support or SLA. All Free tier customers are on the same instance and subject to fair usage. Receive dedicated support, SLA, and improve performance by upgrading to the Pro tier, or Enterprise tier.

So I believe it supports Audio/Video call in free tier as wel.